# Restricting access to API from everywhere except one website

Tags: api, flask

I am creating an API (using Flask if it matters), and I want to access it from another website, using JS. I don't want it to be accessible from anywhere else. I have already configured CORS so that no other website could access the API, but I want it to also be inaccessible through Docker, `python.requests`, and similar tools. Is there any way to do that?

I've heard that I need to set an API key, but as I see it, because I want to access the API from another website through JS, the key will be visible in Web Inspector, and it won't make sense at all. Any suggestions to help me restrict access?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your other website is completely public and open there is not really any way to protect the API. You can make it harder to access, by adding cors and checking the origin headers in your backend and deny acces from anything that doesn't look like a browser from your expected origin. Ofcourse this can be faked. If you want some proper security, you would need to add some way of identifying each individual user of your website. They can then request an access token from your API (or a separate one) and then use that to access it further.